# Facing an error "*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size (fast)"

Tags: linux, java-native-interface, centos

Please see MSO question [A long list of possible duplicates — C memory allocation and overrunning bounds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254782/a-long-list-of-possible-duplicates-c-memory-allocation-and-overrunning-bounds) for information about closely related questions.

---

Developer environment: CentOS 4.7, Kdevelop 3.1.1, gcc 3.4.6

I run a Java test client that loads a C++ shared library using JNI. There are three components in my application,

1. Java client
2. C++ shared library which acts as a JNI wrapper. (I will call it "wrapperlibrary")
3. C++ shared library containing business objects. (I will call it "businesslibrary")

When I run the client I face an error very frequently which is, `*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x080eeef8 ***`. This error comes for around 10 - 11 times and then the application runs.

In my Java client, I first load the required C++ libraries in a static ctor as follows,

```
static
{
System.Load("/root/Desktop/libs/businesslibrary");
System.out.println("business library loaded");
System.Load("/root/Desktop/libs/wrapperlibrary");
System.out.println("wrapper library loaded");
}
```

The statement "business library loaded" gets printed on the console but after it the error `*** glibc...` comes.

In the project settings of wrapperlibrary, the businesslibrary is specified as a dependant library. So, even if I omit the call to load businesslibrary and just write,

```
static
{
System.Load("/root/Desktop/libs/wrapperlibrary");
System.out.println("wrapper library loaded");
}
```

then firstly the businesslibrary gets loaded(seen through global variable creation logging) and then the wrapperlibrary gets loaded. The control returns back to java client and the statement "wrapper library loaded" is printed on console. After this there is a call 
to native method. But the control never reaches this native method's implementation. Rather before that the error `*** glibc...` again comes. Also if I insert a call to static method of another java class before native method call such as,

```
static
{
 System.Load("/root/Desktop/libs/wrapperlibrary");
 System.out.println("wrapper library loaded");
 System.out.println(Try.temp()); //where temp is a static method of Try class which returns a string.

 native method call;

 --
 --
}
```

then output of Try.temp() never gets printed.

What could be the possible reasons for the problem in both these approaches and how should I proceed?

Comment: Seems to be problem in your shared library.

Comment: @Laurynas - Valgrind showed me two errors but mentioned only addresses not the actual code even on a debug build. So, don't know what to do next. Pasting a snipped of output for lack of space.

==23002== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==23002==    at 0x246: ???
==23002==  Address 0x246 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==23002==
==23002== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==23002==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x246
==23002==    at 0x246: ???

Comment: @Adil - The shared library works fine when used with a C++ executable but gives problem when loaded through Java. I have seen that the problem apparently comes during loading phase of shared library.

Comment: @HS Address 0x246 looks definitely wrong as a jump target. Are there further lines that say not "at 0xADDRESS" but rather "by 0xADDRESS"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that Java itself is linked against a different glibc than your libraries or that the libraries are linked differently/to different glibcs.
Also check if one of the libraries is linking against a debug version of the glibc (hat that problem on windows with the C++ runtime lib).
Try linking your libraries staticly against the glibc, or for the sake of excluding possibilities linking your wrapper and business libs staticly into one library.

Comment: The solution is somewhat similar to your suggestion - it relates to linking. The business library has its own overridden implementation of wide char apis since it is working on 2 byte Unicode. It was expected to link to these apis but rather got dynamically linked to system apis which expect a size of 4. I have changed the names of overridden apis to correct this. Now both the wrapper and business library link with the overridden apis. Thanks.

Comment: @HS: If you solve a problem yourself, you can post the solution as answer and accept that, so that others can find it.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this cryptic error several times.

In each case it was caused by referencing an array member that was outside of the array. The reference did not cause a segmentation fault, as it was still within the bounds of another array in the program. When I went to free the array, however, things were messed up enough to throw this error.

The fix was to very carefully check that each array was properly allocated, and that references to array members never went out of bounds.