# free(): invalid next size (fast) - Freeing a struct of string array in c

Tags: c, memory-management

Hello I am trying to free a linked list I have created and I'm having some real trouble.

My System is Ubuntu 10.10 and I am using the gcc compiler. I have to use a makefile and separate source files compilation. 
This is the head of the makefile

```
OBJS    = main.o Buffer.o ExtMerge.o MySet.o
SOURCE  = main.c Buffer.c ExtMerge.c MySet.c
HEADER  = MyHeader.h Buffer.h ExtMerge.h MySet.h
OUT     = myjoin
CC  = gcc
FLAGS   = -g -c
```

The programm is part of an external sorting programm.It reads a bulk of records from a file, inserts them to the List sorted and writes them to part files.So far everything is going as it should. Then another file is opened. At this point, it would be wise to free the memory so that the new List (containing data from say file2) doesn't cost extra memory.

Let me show you my code:
The nodes of the List:

```
struct record{

    char    **field;
    struct  record  *next;
    };
```

This function inserts an array of tokens (read from the file) to the list ordered:
cols_no is the number of strings in the array, column is the one of interest.
The following malloc stuff works just perfect

```
struct record *OrderedInsertRec(struct record *buf, char **arr, int column, int cols_no)
{   struct  record  *aux=NULL;
    int i;

if ( buf==NULL ) { 
            buf = (struct record *) malloc (sizeof(struct record)+1);
            buf->field=(char **)calloc(cols_no, sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i <= cols_no; ++i){
        buf->field[i] = (char*)malloc(((strlen(arr[i])+1))*sizeof(char*));
        strcpy(buf->field[i],arr[i]);
    }

            buf->next = NULL;
    return(buf);
            }                 
else if ( strverscmp (buf->field[column], arr[column]) < 0 ) {  
    buf->next = OrderedInsertRec (buf->next, arr, column, cols_no);
    return(buf);
    }
else    {
    aux = (struct record *) malloc (sizeof(struct record)+1);
            aux->field=(char **)calloc(cols_no, sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i <= cols_no; ++i){
        aux->field[i] = malloc(strlen(arr[i])+1);
        strcpy(aux->field[i],arr[i]);
    }

            aux->next = NULL;
    aux->next = buf;
    return(aux);
            }
```

}

This is causing my trouble:

```
struct record * DeleteBuffer(struct record * buf, int cols_no)
{
int i;

struct record * tmp;

while(buf != NULL)
{

    tmp = buf; 
    buf = buf->next;
    }
free(tmp);
}
```

}

This works without any problem but does nothing. Only a small amount of memory is freed(I suppose beacause I only free the pointer I have allocated in OrderedInsert and not the field[] array) as I can see from the System Monitor

Then I tried this:

```
struct record * DeleteBuffer(struct record * buf, int cols_no)
{
int i;


struct record * tmp;
while(buf != NULL)
{

    tmp = buf; 
    buf = buf->next;
    for (i = 0; i <= cols_no; ++i){

        free(tmp->field[i]);
    }

free(tmp);
}
}
}
```

And this is what i got:
{

```
*** glibc detected *** ./myjoin: double free or corruption (out): 0x088b3010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6c501)[0xb766e501]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6dd70)[0xb766fd70]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb7672e5d]
./myjoin[0x8048bee]
./myjoin[0x80495b4]
./myjoin[0x8048a10]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0xb7618ce7]
./myjoin[0x8048791]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804b000 r-xp 00000000 fb:03 2999566    /home/giorgos/Desktop/test11/myjoin
0804b000-0804c000 r--p 00002000 fb:03 2999566    /home/giorgos/Desktop/test11/myjoin
0804c000-0804d000 rw-p 00003000 fb:03 2999566    /home/giorgos/Desktop/test11/myjoin
088a0000-088c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b74d3000-b74ed000 r-xp 00000000 fb:03 3940432    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b74ed000-b74ee000 r--p 00019000 fb:03 3940432    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b74ee000-b74ef000 rw-p 0001a000 fb:03 3940432    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7500000-b7521000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7521000-b7600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7601000-b7602000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7602000-b7759000 r-xp 00000000 fb:03 3940764    /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
b7759000-b775b000 r--p 00157000 fb:03 3940764    /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
b775b000-b775c000 rw-p 00159000 fb:03 3940764    /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
b775c000-b775f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b776d000-b7772000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7772000-b7773000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7773000-b778f000 r-xp 00000000 fb:03 3940761    /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
b778f000-b7790000 r--p 0001b000 fb:03 3940761    /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
b7790000-b7791000 rw-p 0001c000 fb:03 3940761    /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
bfb1a000-bfb3b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

}

What should I do. Is it a problem with my malloc??
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that I tried to do this as well with the same results:
buf->field[i] = (char*)malloc((MAXSIZE)*sizeof(char*));
where
MAXSIZE=128, which is way more than the strings in the file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facing an error "\*\*\* glibc detected \*\*\* free(): invalid next size (fast)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317021/facing-an-error-glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-fast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three problems. You malloc/calloc:

> ```
>       buf = (struct record *) malloc (sizeof(struct record)+1);
>       buf->field=(char **)calloc(cols_no, sizeof(char*));
> ```

Why `sizeof(struct record)+1`? What's the `+1` for?

You `calloc()` `cols_no` items of size `sizeof(char*)`, yet your two for-loop's go from 0...cols, when it should go from 0...cols-1.

> ```
>    for (i = 0; i <= cols_no; ++i){
> ```

should be:

> ```
>    for (i = 0; i < cols_no; ++i){
> ```

You should be allocating `(strlen(arr[i])+1)*sizeof(char)` -- using `sizeof(char*)` is probably 4-8x too much, assuming `sizeof(char)` == 1 and `sizeof(char*)` == 4 or 8 depending on 32-bit or 64bit ptrs.

> ```
>       buf->field[i] = (char*)malloc(((strlen(arr[i])+1))*sizeof(char*));
> ```

should be:

> ```
>       buf->field[i] = (char*)malloc(((strlen(arr[i])+1))*sizeof(char));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
calloc(cols_no, sizeof(char*))
...
for (i = 0; i <= cols_no; ++i)
```

You're mixing whether cols_no is *number of columns* or *index of last column*.

Try changing all your loops from `<=cols_no` to `<cols_no`

If you have `cols_no` elements in an array, the valid array indexes are **`0..cols_no-1`**

Comment: You were right about that but still the same:
*** glibc detected *** ./myjoin: double free or corruption (out):

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you!!!!
This fixed the errors
       for (i = 0; i < cols_no; ++i){

I forgot to change the "aux" for loop

Comment: Although I still don't seem to be getting any memory back... Like not even a byte. I use the System Monitor to view the memory changes. It changes only upwards...

Comment: I have added counters and the memory that should be freed is = 7 kbytes