# realloc():invalid next size

Tags: realloc

so I have some code that works fine with small text files but crashes with larger ones. The point of the code is to take a file and a parameter n, parse through the code and save everything in a 2d array in chucks of size n. So buffer[0][0]through [0][n-1] should hold n characters, and buffer[1][0]through [1][n-1] should hold the next n chunk, and so on. My code works when the file only has a few words, but with a larger file I get an error saying realloc():invalid next size. Any ideas why? Here is my code.

```
void bsort(int n)
{
    int numwords= 0;
    int numlets=0;
    char ** buffer=(char**)malloc(numwords*n); 
    while (!feof(stdin))
    {
        char l= getchar();
        if (l!= EOF) 
        {
            if (numlets%n==0)
            {
                numwords=numwords+1;
                buffer=(char**)realloc(buffer,numwords*n);
                if(!buffer)
                {
                    printf("Allocation error!");
                }
                buffer[numwords-1]= (char*) malloc (n);
                buffer[numwords-1][numlets%n]=l;
                // printf("%c", buffer[numwords-1][numlets%n]);
                numlets=numlets+1;
            }
        }

        int i,j;
        for (i=0; i < numwords; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j< n; j++)
            {
                printf("%c",buffer[i][j]);
            }

        }
```

Comment: nothing too large, just like 3000 bytes or so. This stops working after 20 characters or so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facing an error "\*\*\* glibc detected \*\*\* free(): invalid next size (fast)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317021/facing-an-error-glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-fast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if each time you get a character, you are reallocating your buffer. That seems a little off to me. Have you thought of allocating some space, doing a memset to `\0`, and just managing the current size and buffer size separately?

It may be that realloc is having issues with a pointer to nothing at first. If it fails after the first character input, you might be having issues with your first `malloc()`. Pre-allocating some space would solve that.

Comment: The way I have it, I allocate more space everytime I get an n chuck of characters. I dont really see how I can preallocate space when I dont know how many characters are in the file I'm parsing. When I'm debugging it, everything works till buffer[2][n-1], and wont reallocate after that (which in the test I'm running is only 10 spaces, as n=5)

Comment: It looks like you're allocating after each character is read in by `getchar()`... To pre-allocate, you allocate a set amount, like 101 characters or so. I like to `memset()` everything to `\0` to make sure no functions run off the end as well. Once you ahve read in 100 characters, you can add 100 characters of space on the end and `memcpy()` everything over to the new buffer. It cuts down on the allocations you have to do but increases your work by just a little bit.

Comment: The allocation clause is inside if (numlets%n==0), so it only goes to that when a chunk of n characters have been parsed. And I dont think allocating that much at a time will work because I have to keep only n character in each part of the array

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `malloc(0)` is not guaranteed to return a useful pointer you can `realloc()`.

The [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) only guarantees that `malloc(0)` returns either null or a pointer that can safely be used to call `free()`.