# "realloc(): invalid next size"

Tags: c

*Alternatively: duplicate of [Facing an error — glibc detected free invalid next size (fast)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317021/facing-an-error-glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-fast).*

When I compile and run this code, I get an error message:
"realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000002483010"

I've been trying to find a solution for this for the last 6 hours without any luck..

Here are the relevant parts of my code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct vertex
{
    char* name;
    int id;
    int outDegree;
}vertex;

int main(){
    vertex *tmpVertice;
    vertex *vertices = (vertex*)calloc(1, sizeof(vertex));
    int p=1;
    while(p<20){
        vertex temp={"hi",p,0};
        vertices[p-1]=temp;
        tmpVertice=(vertex*)realloc(vertices,p);
        if(tmpVertice!=NULL) vertices=tmpVertice;
        p++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to `free` after calling `realloc`.

Comment: Is casting `realloc` as un-recommended as casting `malloc`?

Comment: `tmpVertice=(vertex*)realloc(vertices,p);` <- that's `p` bytes, you want `p*sizeof *vertices`.

Comment: How about reading the documentation of the function you're trying to use? Or googling for an example?

Comment: @KevinDTimm Yes, it definitely is.

Comment: @DanielFischer How about `p * sizeof(*tmpVertice)` instead? (`sizeof(type)` will break if the type ever changes.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Right, but I forgot how the pointer was named.

Comment: @DanielFischer In this case, no worries.

Comment: Why is there a realloc in there at all? And why is calloc being used for the initial allocation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[realloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) frees any previous buffer if necessary so the lines `free(vertices)` and `free(tmpVertice)` in your loop are wrong and should be removed.

Edit: I've included an updated version of your program below with further fixes.  You needed to `realloc` `p*sizeof(vertex)` rather than `p` bytes.  You were writing beyond the end of the array then growing it.  I've changed to `realloc` at the start of the loop

```
int main(){
    vertex *tmpVertice;
    vertex *vertices = NULL;
    int p=1;
    while(p<20){
        vertex temp={"hi",p,0};
        tmpVertice=realloc(vertices,p*sizeof(vertex));
        if(tmpVertice==NULL) {
            printf("ERROR: realloc failed\n");
            return -1;
        }
        vertices=tmpVertice;
        vertices[p-1]=temp;

        p++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks but after removing them I still get the same error message

Comment: @Roy I've updated my answer to cover the other changes you need to make

Answer (score 0):

At the first iteration, you will access to `vertices[p-1] = vertices[2-1] = vertices[1]`, but you alloc only 1 byte (you can access just to vertices[0]).

Comment: thank you but after changing p to 1 I still get the same error message