# realloc invalid next size

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

*Alternatively, duplicate of [Facing an error — glibc detected free invalid next size (fast)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317021/facing-an-error-glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-fast).*

I have been struggling with this, I tried using valgrind to track it down but can't seem to pin down the exact source of the error. I can call the function 4 times, but after that it throws the realloc invalid next size error.

The exact error: *** glibc detected *** ./matrix: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000001a46010 ***

Here's the code:

```
char line[101];
int nMatrix = -1;
Dims *dimensions;
List *vals = NULL;
int **values;
int **columns;
int **rowPointer;
int *lineCount;
int *highestRow;

void newMatrix()
{
    nMatrix++;
    values = realloc(values, sizeof(int*));
    columns = realloc(columns, sizeof(int*));
    rowPointer = realloc(rowPointer, sizeof(int*));
    dimensions = realloc(dimensions, sizeof(Dims));
    lineCount = realloc(lineCount, sizeof(int));
    highestRow = realloc(highestRow, sizeof(int));
}

void readIn(char* inputFile, int transpose)
{
    FILE *fr;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    newMatrix();
    if((fr = fopen(inputFile, "r")) != NULL)
    {
        while(fgets(line, 100, fr) != NULL)
        {
            if(lineCount[nMatrix] == 0)
            {
                if(transpose)
                    sscanf(line, "%d,%d", &dimensions[nMatrix].n, &dimensions[nMatrix].m);
                else
                    sscanf(line, "%d,%d", &dimensions[nMatrix].m, &dimensions[nMatrix].n);
                printf("nMatrix = %d, n%d,m%d\n", nMatrix, dimensions[nMatrix].n, dimensions[nMatrix].m);
            }
            else
            {
                sscanf(line, "%d,%d,%d", &a,&b,&c);
                //printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a,b,c);
                //rows[a] = insertList(c,b,rows[a]);c
                if(transpose)
                    vals = insertList(c, a, b, dimensions[nMatrix].m, dimensions[nMatrix].n, vals);
                else
                    vals = insertList(c, b, a, dimensions[nMatrix].m, dimensions[nMatrix].n, vals);
            }
            lineCount[nMatrix]++;
        }
        values[nMatrix] = calloc(lineCount[nMatrix], sizeof(int));
        columns[nMatrix] = calloc(lineCount[nMatrix], sizeof(int));
        rowPointer[nMatrix] = calloc(((dimensions[nMatrix].m)+1), sizeof(int));
        values[nMatrix][lineCount[nMatrix]] = 0;
        columns[nMatrix][lineCount[nMatrix]] = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int lastRow = -1;
        while(i < dimensions[nMatrix].m)
        {
            rowPointer[nMatrix][i] = -1;
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        List *temp = NULL;
        while(vals != NULL)
        {
            temp = vals;
            //printf("pos = %d, row = %d, col = %d, val = %d, i=%d", temp->position, temp->row, temp->column, temp->value, i);
            if(lastRow != temp->row)
            {
                rowPointer[nMatrix][temp->row] = i;
                lastRow = temp->row;
                highestRow[nMatrix] = i;
            }
            values[nMatrix][i] = temp->value;
            columns[nMatrix][i] = temp->column;
            i++;
            vals = temp->next;
            free(temp);

        }
        rowPointer[nMatrix][dimensions[nMatrix].m] = lineCount[nMatrix]-1;
        fclose(fr);
        return;
    }
    fclose(fr);
    printf("File not found\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your post.

Comment: Which function is giving you error ?

Comment: readIn, I can call it 4 times, but any more than that causes the malloc error

Comment: What's the ERNO value you are getting?

Comment: Have you looked up what `realloc()` actually does, and what the arguments to it are?

Comment: Reading over realloc again I realised I have been stupid, the second arguement should be the total size of the new block. I think I have got it, let me try something and get back to you guys.

Comment: I changed the second argument  of realloc to nMatrix*sizeof(int) (or whatever the datatype is for that particular line) and the error is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With each new matrix you "allocate", you should be *expanding* your global pointer lists. you don't. You just reallocate them to the same size the were before:

This:

```
void newMatrix()
{
    nMatrix++;
    values = realloc(values, sizeof(int*));
    columns = realloc(columns, sizeof(int*));
    rowPointer = realloc(rowPointer, sizeof(int*));
    dimensions = realloc(dimensions, sizeof(Dims));
    lineCount = realloc(lineCount, sizeof(int));
    highestRow = realloc(highestRow, sizeof(int));
}
```

Should be this:

```
void newMatrix()
{
    nMatrix++;
    values = realloc(values, (nMatrix+1)*sizeof(int*));
    columns = realloc(columns, (nMatrix+1)*sizeof(int*));
    rowPointer = realloc(rowPointer, (nMatrix+1)*sizeof(int*));
    dimensions = realloc(dimensions, (nMatrix+1)*sizeof(Dims));
    lineCount = realloc(lineCount, (nMatrix+1)*sizeof(int));
    highestRow = realloc(highestRow, (nMatrix+1)*sizeof(int));
}
```

Note: the `(nMatrix+1)` value is used because you start with `nMatrix` as `(-1)`, and upon first increment it is `(0)`, the next is `(1)`, etc... I.e. it always indexes the last row inserted, but your vector magnitudes needs to be +1 to that for hopefully obvious reasons.

I would strongly suggest you consider what happens when `realloc()` fails as well, as it will return NULL and in the process leak whatever memory *was* pointed to by the pointer you passed in.

There may be other issues, but that was the first one that jumped out at me.

Comment: I just realised this and tested it out, the problem is that its now segfaulting, running gdb yields:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_int_free (av=0x7ffff7ad7740 <main_arena>, p=0x605360, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4054
4054 malloc.c: No such file or directory.

Comment: @ethangk Once you apply the above, rerun this under valgrind. Somewhere in your main code loops you're likely stomping on memory, but at least you *have* memory to stomp on now. Furthermore, nowhere in this code is a `free()` call to be seen except *one*, and that one you should look at pretty carefully. It is freeing memory that isn't even allocated here (it is allocated in `insertList()`). The actual exposure is wherever you're cleaning up. Either way, the code pointed out in this answer is *wrong* and should be addressed as described.

Comment: I reran it under valgrind, strangely it ran the code all the way through. There is a free() call towards the bottom of the readIn function. In the code I was testing on, I had changed the 3 calloc calls to malloc, I changed them back and the code now works. Thanks so much, I'll address the points you made.

Comment: @ethangk always a bridesmaid...

Comment: @WhozCraig: not sure how to contact you about the question you deleted, so I am posting here, hope it's OK. filtering the results on Google by date seems to show that the Web knows about "decay" at least since 1993... in particular, I would say this is one of the most ancient, "relevant" links (search for the only occurrence of `decay` on that page): http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/msb-on-b.html.

Comment: @AndyProwl that's amazing it goes that far back, and even there, its almost matter-of-fact. That is easily the oldest reference I've seen to it, and would be in lock-step with the timeline of post-1991, where until then I'd never heard of it at all. Thanks, sir.