# realloc() abruptly aborts the C program

Tags: c, unix, realloc

Kindly note that I have already gone through

[Facing an error "*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size (fast)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317021/facing-an-error-glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-fast)

but, I didnt find it helpful.

I want to dynamicaly create an array of strings, with filenames as the strings.

**Here is my code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{  
    DIR         *dir = NULL;
    struct dirent   *file = NULL;
    int         i = 0;
    unsigned short  len;

    if ( (dir = opendir(".") ) == NULL ) {
        if (errno != 0) {
            perror("Unable to open current directory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    char    **filename = NULL;

    while ( (file = readdir(dir)) != NULL ) {

        if (i == 0) 
            filename = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(i+1));     
        else 
            filename = realloc(filename,i+1);


        filename[i] = strdup (file->d_name);
        printf("%s  ", filename[i] );
        i += 1;
    } 
    if ( errno != 0 ) {
        perror("Unable to read from the current directory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    if (dir != NULL) {
        if (closedir(dir) == -1) {
            if (errno != 0) {
                perror("Unable to close the current directory");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    } 
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the **output** :

```
*** Error in `./a.out': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00000000016d6050 ***
realloc.c  StackOverflow  a.out  num_ip_using_scanf.c  Aborted
```

Initially for few filenemes it did fine, but suddenly it aborts with the above error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An issue is that you don't check if `filename` is NULL after the `realloc` or `malloc` call.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah I should have checked for that, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: A file name is (usually) longer than 1 or two characters.  Your malloc is only for 1 or 2 characters.  The malloc actually needs to be for the full length of the file name, as contained in the file->d_name member of the file structure. The dup operation copies characters into the heap, past the allocated area, thereby corrupting the heap.  This is what is causing the crash.  Note athere are several other errors in the program, but this is the main one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong reallocation.

```
// filename = realloc(filename, i+1);
filename = realloc(filename,(i+1) * sizeof *filename);`
```

BTW: No need to differentiate memory allocation calls.  Since the pointer is initialized to `NULL`, use `realloc()` the first and subsequent times.

```
char **filename = NULL;
...
// if (i == 0) filename = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(i+1));     
// else filename = realloc(filename,i+1);
filename = realloc(filename,(i+1) * sizeof *filename);`
```

@PaulMcKenzie well points out code should check for problem return values.  Further, `fileanme` should be `free()` in the end.

Comment: Yeah this solution works perfectly fine. I am actually used to doing something as follows :
filename = realloc(filename,(i+1)*sizeof(char*));
but, now as per your solution I came to know that I can simply dereference the pointer.