# c libmysql: free(): invalid next size (normal)

Tags: c, linux, libmysql

When I comment the indicated line, I don't have any problem. But when I dont I get the "free(): invalid next size (normal)" error. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code- Main.c:

```
MYSQL_RES *result = run_query("SELECT * FROM Zones");
int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) 
{ 
    for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) 
  { 
      printf("%s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL"); 
  } 
      printf("\n"); 
}
mysql_free_result(result);             /*Problem is with this line*/
```

And here's the run_query() function:

```
MYSQL_RES* run_query(char query[200]) {

    if (mysql_query(con, query)) 
    {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }

    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);

    if (result == NULL) 
    {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }
    else{
        return result;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should check for NULL.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). You don't need your `run_query` (you should call directly [mysql_real_query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-query.html)). I guess you could have a memory leak *elsewhere*.

Comment: I used valgrind and the program doesn't crash. No errors reported.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2317021/841108) could be related.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: free(): invalid next size (fast):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/error-free-invalid-next-size-fast)