# Problem when trying to allocate memory in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I'm having a problem when using `realloc()` in one function and with the same algorithm, it doesn't work for the other. I can't understand where I'm making a mistake.

For the `initVertex` function this algorithm works fine. But in the `initFace` every time I try to allocate memory for the `faces` it says:

```
realloc(): invalid next size.
```

The files I'm reading from is in `.obj` format:

for vertex:   v  -0.187264 0.10108 0.266814

for face:    f  938/938/936 944/944/942 936/936/934

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#include "Scene.h"

#define MAX_ID 10
#define LIMIT 10
#define MEM_INCREASE 10


void setArrToZero(char *arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < LIMIT; ++i) {
        *(arr + i) = 0;
    }
}

void initFace(Object *obj, char *line, int length, int *maxFaces) {
    int i = 0, strCounter = 0;
    (obj->faces)[obj->numberOfFaces].size = 0;
    (obj->faces)[obj->numberOfFaces].vertex = (int*) malloc(MAX_ID * sizeof(int));
    char *numStr = (char*) malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    enum boolean flag = FALSE;
    if (obj->numberOfFaces == *maxFaces) {
        obj->faces = (Face*) realloc(obj->faces,
                (*maxFaces + MEM_INCREASE) * sizeof(Face));
        *maxFaces += 10;
    }
    while (i != length) {
        char c = line[i];
        if (c == ' ' && flag == FALSE)    //turn the flag on
            flag = TRUE;
        if (c == '/' && flag == TRUE) { //turn the flag off and initialize Face.
            flag = FALSE;
            (obj->faces)[obj->numberOfFaces].vertex[obj->faces->size] = atoi(
                    numStr);
            (obj->faces)[obj->numberOfFaces].size++; // increase number of vertexes of the face.
            setArrToZero(numStr);
            strCounter = 0;
        }
        if (flag == TRUE) {
            numStr[strCounter] = c;
            strCounter++;
        }
        if ((obj->faces)[obj->numberOfFaces].size == MAX_ID) {
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }
    obj->numberOfFaces++;
    free(numStr);
}

void initVertex(Object *obj, char *line, int *maxVertexes) {
    float x, y, z;
    if (line[1] != ' ')
        return;
    else {
        if (obj->numberOfVertexes == *maxVertexes) {
            obj->vertexes = (Vertex*) realloc(obj->vertexes,
                    sizeof(Vertex) * (*maxVertexes + MEM_INCREASE));
            *maxVertexes += 10;
        }
        sscanf(line, "%*[^-0123456789]%f%*[^-0123456789]%f%*[^-0123456789]%f",
                &x, &y, &z);
        (obj->vertexes)[obj->numberOfVertexes].x = x;
        (obj->vertexes)[obj->numberOfVertexes].y = y;
        (obj->vertexes)[obj->numberOfVertexes].z = z;
        obj->numberOfVertexes++;
    }
}

Object* createObject(char *fileName) {
    Object *obj = (Object*) malloc(sizeof(Object));
    int maxVertexes = 10, maxFaces = 10;
    obj->numberOfFaces = 0;
    obj->numberOfVertexes = 0;
    obj->vertexes = (Vertex*) malloc(maxVertexes * sizeof(Vertex));
    obj->faces = (Face*) malloc(maxFaces * sizeof(Face));
    FILE *inputF;
    size_t len = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    inputF = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (inputF == NULL) {
        printf("File not exist!");
        return NULL;
    }
    while (!feof(inputF)) {
        getline(&line, &len, inputF);
        char c = line[0];
        switch (c) {
        case 'v':
            initVertex(obj, line, &maxVertexes);
            break;
        case 'f':
            initFace(obj, line, len, &maxFaces);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

int main() {


    Object *obj = createObject("Donald.obj");
    printf("done");

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Facing an error "\*\*\* glibc detected \*\*\* free(): invalid next size (fast)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317021/facing-an-error-glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-fast)

Comment: Use valgrind to debug your code, you probably have some buffer overrun. See linked question.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but the `while (!feof(inputF))` doesn't sound correct to me. See [Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: `fopen` can fail for many reasons even when the file does exist.  Printing the string "File not exist!" when there is a permissions error will (not "may", but "will") cause unnecessary confusion and time lost.  Print a reasonable error message. `if(inputF == NULL) { perror(fileName); return NULL; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initVertex()` reallocates the array `vertexes` *before* it uses the out-of-bound index `numberOfVertexes`.

`initFace()` uses the out-of-bound index `numberOfFaces` twice here:

```
    (obj->faces)[obj->numberOfFaces].size = 0;
    (obj->faces)[obj->numberOfFaces].vertex = (int*) malloc(MAX_ID * sizeof(int));
```

and only *after* having done reallocates the array `faces`.

Accessing the array `faces` out of bound provokes undefined behaviour. Anything can happen from then one. In this particular case the program's memory management seems to have been messed up.